# Writing a test in Laravel to determine if ORM items are in the correct order

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, tdd, eloquent

I wrote a test to pull 10 articles from my database.  I then wrote the code to make the test pass and it works.  However, now I want to write a test to make sure the 10 articles I pull from the database are in `descending order` based on `created_at`.  I'm not sure how to go about this, at all.

Test Method:

```
public function testPullTenArticles()
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++)
    {
        $tempArticle = new Article;
        $tempArticle->save();
    }

    $this->assertEquals(10, count($this->article->getArticles(10)));
}
```

Real Method:

```
public function getArticles($count)
{
    $articles = Article::take($count)->get();
    return $articles;
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using something like this https://github.com/laracasts/TestDummy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the `orderBy` clause to retrieve your objects, then you shouldn't need to test it - the good folks who wrote the Laravel & Eloquent code have already done that.

You can order your collection like this:

```
$articles = Article::orderBy("created_at", "desc")->take($count)->get();
```

Comment: should I be creating a `mock` object for `Article`?

Comment: No, I'm saying you shouldn't bother testing it at all. You wrote "I want to write a test to make sure the 10 articles I pull from the database are in `descending order` based on `created_at`" - essentially, you want to test the `orderBy` method. Why bother? Laravel & Eloquent have unit tests of their own to test that method - no need to duplicate those tests.

Comment: I see.  I am trying to do TDD, though, so I feel like I'm not supposed to create the logic until I have a test for it.  I'm new to this, though, so I could be wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty new to TDD too, so I can see where you're coming from. But in this case, you're writing what is basically a one-line wrapper for a method provided by Eloquent which we can assume has been thoroughly tested. Look at it this way: is your `getArticles` method really adding anything to your code? You could just as easily replace your calls to `getArticles()` with `Article::orderBy(...)->take(...)->get()`

Comment: I agree with @Kryten. It may help to realize that you're technically dealing with an *integration* test and not a *unit* test. Since you're testing a boundary of your code (i.e., the integration of your code with the Laravel/Eloquent code), the approach will be slightly different than with your unit tests, where you can more easily use test doubles. As @Kryten mentioned, your `getArticles` method doesn't do much - it only invokes the external code. This is a *good* thing. Now you have a seam in your code that will effectively allow the rest of your code to mock out this dependency.